# Como leer valores nulos y no nulos de un datatable en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar a este problema.

Tengo un DataTable con 3 columnas de las cuales tienen el siguente formato:

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Como puedo recorrer este datatable y agregar los datos a un nuevo datatable sin los signos de $ ni % incluyendo los valores vacíos o nulos como se muestra en la imagen?.**

id_Persona ----- tipo int

Sueldo ---- tipo float

Pago ------ tipo float

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de mi Data Table original incluye los símbolos.

```
string nombre_usuario = t.Consultar_Datos(usuario.Name).Usuario;
        string path_ArchivoExcel = HttpContext.Current.Session["fileLocation"].ToString();
        DataTable datos_HojaExcel = new DataTable();           
        datos_HojaExcel = HttpContext.Current.Session["dtExcel"] as DataTable;
        DataView dv = new DataView(datos_HojaExcel);
        DataTable datos_Actualizar = dv.ToTable(false, "id_Persona", "SUELDO", "Pago");
```

Comment: Pero que llevas de codigo? y cual es tu pregunta especifica?

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate ya edite mi pregunte espero me puedas ayudar gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con las extensiones de `linq`

Creas una clase como ser

```
public class ExcelData{
   public int PersonaId {get;set;}
   public decimal Sueldo {get;set;}
   public decimal Pago {get;set;}
}
```

Entonces conviertes usando

```
var result = from row in datos_Actualizar.AsEnumerable()
             select new ExcelData(){
                  PersonaId = row.Field<int>("Id_Persona")
                  Sueldo = Decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("Sueldo"), NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol)
                  Pago = Decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("Pago"), NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol)
             };

DataTable dtResult = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Aqui

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Explica con mas detalle como usar el `CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: Puedes iniciar como dice @Leandro solo agrega que tus propiedades sueldo y pago pueden ser nulas para diferenciarlas de un valor real 0,  public decimal? Sueldo {get;set;} public decimal? Pago{get; set;} en las conversiones Decimal primero revisa que row.Field 'sueldo' si no son nulas realizas la conversion y si no es un valor nulo